# Await Async call in javascript doesn't console.log in Node js

Tags: javascript

I've been reading up on promises for a few hours and I'm loosing my mind here.  According to what I've read in SO and articles on google.  To get the value of a response in a variable I have to use async and await.  So going that route I've written this code:

```
async function getZpid() {

let response = await function getZillowZpid(){
zillow.get('GetSearchResults', parameters)
    .then(results => {
      let zpidResponse = results.response.results.result[0].zpid;
      console.log("i ran");
      return zpidResponse;
  });
}

}

getZpid();
```

Here I would expect that when `getZpid()` runs "response" would wait for the function get `ZillowZpid` to be done.  Once it would be completed it would `console.log` "i ran" and then return the zpidResponse.

I get no error but the `console.log` never appears.  Ultimately the `console.log` is just a test what I am trying to do is get zpidResponse in to a variable I could use outside the function.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are defining an extraneous function with `await function getZillowZpid()` which you never call. This is why you see no error or results. If you log the variable `response` in your function above you will see that it is something `[Function: getZillowZpid]`, you've defined a function and assigned it to `response` which is certainly not what you want.

Since `zillow.get` returns a promise, you can just await that. Here's an example with a mocked `zillow` object:

```js
// fake the zillow object
let zillow = {
  get() {
    return Promise.resolve({response: {results: {result: [{zpid: "Some data"}]}}})
  }
}

async function getZpid() {
  let parameters = {}
  // zillow.get returns a promise, you can use await to get the returned value
  let response = await zillow.get('GetSearchResults', parameters)
      .then(results => {
        let zpidResponse = results.response.results.result[0].zpid;
        console.log("i ran");
        return zpidResponse;
    });
  
  console.log(response)
  }
  
  getZpid();
```

FYI, if you're using `async/await` it's cleaner to avoid the `then()` although you still should add some error-checking:

```js
// fake zillow
let zillow = {
  get() {
    return Promise.resolve({response: {results: {result: [{zpid: "Some data"}]}}})
  }
}
async function getZpid() {
  let parameters = 0
  let response = await zillow.get('GetSearchResults', parameters)
  let zpidResponse = response.response.results.result[0].zpid;
  console.log(zpidResponse)
  return zpidResponse
  }

  getZpid();
```

Comment: With this it returns Promise { <pending> } any way to get the actual value outside of the function?  @Mark Meyer

Comment: Hi @FabricioG `async` functions always return promises. So fro the caller to get the return value you need to call `getZpid().then(val => /* use value */)`